# when trace element chemistry could be applied to rock systems

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "rock systems" refer to "shake violently social systems"?

> ...and when trace element chemistry could be applied to rock systems.

[image]

Source: [Harvard Education](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1995AREPS..23....1P&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_VIEW&classic=YES)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it means exactly what it says, chemistry applied to actual rocks. It has nothing to do with social systems.